# Unable to style responsive CSS background image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image that displays a different image on mobile, but I'm struggling to set the image responsive dimensions. At the moment, I've had to set a manual width and height, which I'm trying to avoid. If I use 100% as the width and 100% or auto for the height, the image doesn't display at all.

Mark-up:

```
<div id="mts-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide wow slideInDown animated" data-wow-duration=".5s">
<h2>MTS Collective</h2>
<div class="left-half">
<div class="popup-screenshot" id="mts-screenshot"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.white-popup .left-half, .white-popup .right-half {
  margin: 20px;
}
.white-popup .left-half {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.white-popup .right-half {
  width: 40%;
}
.white-popup .popup-screenshot {
  width: 600px;
  height: 456px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.white-popup #mts-screenshot {
  background-image: url("../img/portfolio/mts-browser.png");
}
div#mtsm-popup .left-half {
  width: 30%;
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Because It is doesn't have any width and height. Assign the width and height and it will start show the image.

```
  .white-popup #mts-screenshot {
     background-image: url("../img/portfolio/mts-browser.png");
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
  }
```

Comment: The width and height are currently manually set on `.white-popup .popup-screenshot`, which is the same div. I'm trying to avoid using pixels.

Answer (score 0):

```
add other background properties.
background-position,bg-repeat,bg-color or by shorthand property of background.

Set,

.white-popup {
    width: 1160px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see you have set your parent container, .white-popup as position relative, which is good practice. So, set your left-half and right-half to position: absolute. You can then play with their positions relative to the parent container, .white-popup, and they should remain positioned relative to it. E.g, for .left-side you could do something like left: 2%, top: 10% and .right-side left: 55%, top: 10%. Both width of 40% or something. You can play around with it but you should find something that works a little easier.

All the best!

Comment: @mario Any update to this issue? Hope you solved it!

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I'm still struggling to understand the issue.